# How to check a hash sum file on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, hashsum

### Situation

I'm on FreeBSD 11.2 without GUI. I'm brand new to BSD systems.

Suppose we have a `SHA512SUM` file generated on FreeBSD with:

```
sha512 encrypt-file-aes256 decrypt-file-aes256 > SHA512SUM
```

It looks different from the Linux format, which from Linux can be generated using `--tag` switch:

```
SHA512 (encrypt-file-aes256) = 9170caaa45303d2e5f04c21732500980f3b06fc361018f953127506b56d3f2f46c95efdc291e160dd80e39b5304f327d83fe72c625ab5f31660db9c99dbfd017
SHA512 (decrypt-file-aes256) = 893693eec618542b0b95051952f9258824fe7004c360f8e6056a51638592510a704e27b707b9176febca655b7df581c9a6e2220b6511e8426c1501f6b2dd48a9
```

---

### Question

How do I check this file? There is no `--check` option in the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sha512&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html).

---

### Progress

So far, I am only able to manually test a single file with hard-coding the hash sum:

```
sha512 -c "9170caaa45303d2e5f04c21732500980f3b06fc361018f953127506b56d3f2f46c95efdc291e160dd80e39b5304f327d83fe72c625ab5f31660db9c99dbfd017" encrypt-file-aes256 && echo $?
```

Scripting-wise, I don't yet see a way of checking the whole `SHA512SUM` file automatically.

Note, that it may contain many more files than the two as in my case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `shasum` ([man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=shasum&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports)) tool, which has a `-c` option to check against a checksum file and is a front-end to several checksum algorithms including *SHA-512*.

You can use a command like the one below to check both files:

```
$ shasum -a 512 -c SHA512SUM.sha512sum
```

The `shasum` tool is only able to parse the output format compatible with the one produced by [`sha512sum`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sha512sum) (the tool usually shipped in Linux distributions.)

You can convert from a BSD style checksum file to a Linux style one with a simple `sed` command:

```
$ sed -ne 's/^SHA512 (\(.*\)) = \(.*\)/\2  \1/p' SHA512SUM >SHA512SUM.sha512sum
```

(Though if you're generating the checksums yourself, then also using `shasum` to generate them is a good option, also compatible with the tools found on Linux.)

The `shasum` tool is provided by the FreeBSD port `p5-Digest-SHA` and can be installed with `pkg` by running:

```
$ sudo pkg install p5-Digest-SHA
```